# Format binding value with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, string-formatting

In my application I am binding several text boxes to properties. **So in c# I have:**

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    decimal _Price;
    public decimal Price
    {
       get { return _Price; }
       set
       {
          _Price = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Price");
       }
    }

    // implement interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // etc
```

**and on xaml I have:**

```
   <TextBox Name="txtPrice" DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=c}"></TextBox>
```

then If in my code behind I set the Price = 12.22 for example it will display $12.22 in the textbox.

---

Now because I am using this behavior very often I want to create a class that will create the property binded to the textbox for me. So my class looks like:

```
public class ControlBind<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected T _Value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
                protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    public ControlBind(Control control, System.Windows.DependencyProperty controlPropertyToBind)
    {
        Binding b = new Binding("Value")
        {
            Source = this
        };

        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        control.SetBinding(controlPropertyToBind, b);
    }
}
```

then I will be able to use that class and create the same behavior by doing:

```
// txtPrice is a textbox defined in xaml
ControlBind<decimal> Price = new ControlBind<decimal>(txtPrice, TextBox.TextProperty);

Price.Value = 45; // update textbox value to "45"
```

### but now I don't know how to do the string format. When I use the class, the textbox prints 45 and I want it to print $45

So in other words how can I achieve xaml binding `{Binding Price, StringFormat=c}` in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I think:

```
 Binding b = new Binding("Value")
 {
      Source = this,
      StringFormat = "c"
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it via [Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html).

Can try to code something like this from code behind:

```
public ControlBind(Control control, System.Windows.DependencyProperty controlPropertyToBind)
{
   Binding b = new Binding("Value")
   {
     Source = this,
     Converter = new MyCurrencyConverter() //Converter
   };

   b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
   control.SetBinding(controlPropertyToBind, b);
}
```

Where `MyCurrencyConverter` converts your `45` to `$45`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if I am using a different culture where I want it to print Euro for instance?

Comment: You can take care of it in your implementation of `Convertor`.

Answer (score 0):

To do it purely in code you can just do Price.ToString("C") otherwise @Tigran's solution using converters is the way you want to go.